# Same query, same database, different server, different result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

We have our main database on a server, there is this stored procedure; when we run it against the database, it returns wrong values.

But when I take a back up of this database and restore it on another server and run the exact same query, it returns the correct answer.

What can I do?

Is it possible that the configuration of SQL Server affects how a query returns  results?

If yes where can I start looking for problem ?

Here is the stored procedure, the exact same procedure runs on both databases and both databases are identical.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[S_GheymatGozaryFIFOFroosh]
    @AYear SMALLINT,
    @LDate CHAR(8),
    @OdCd VARCHAR(17), 
    @FromFirst BIT,
    @SCd TINYINT
AS
    DECLARE @LHId Int, @LHRadif SmallInt, 
            @LHFact_Date CHAR(8), @LHFact_No INT,
            @LHStock_Cd TinyInt, @LQnt_Resid DECIMAL(18,4),
            @LPrc_Resid DECIMAL(30,8)
    DECLARE @LRId INT, @LRRadif SmallInt, 
            @LRFact_Date CHAR(8), @LRFact_No INT,
            @LRStock_Cd TinyInt
    DECLARE @Kind_Cd TINYINT, @StartDate CHAR(8)

    DECLARE @Cnt INT 
    SET @Cnt = 0        

    IF @ldate IS NOT NULL AND @FromFirst = 1
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM S_Fifo_Gheymat 
        WHERE (Acc_Year = @Ayear) 
          AND (@SCd = 0 OR H_Stock_Cd = @SCd) 
          AND (Od_Cd = @OdCd)
    END

    IF @SCd = 0 
       SET @Kind_Cd = 2 
    ELSE 
       SET @Kind_Cd = 1

    SET @StartDate = Right(CAST(@AYear AS VARCHAR(4)), 2) + '/01/01' 

    SELECT 
        @LHId = H_Id,
        @LHRadif = H_Radif,
        @LHFact_Date = H_Fact_Date,
        @LHFact_No = H_Fact_No,
        @LHStock_Cd = H_Stock_Cd,
        @LQnt_Resid = Qnt_Resid,
        @LPrc_Resid = Prc_Resid,
        @LRId = R_Id,
        @LRRadif = R_Radif,
        @LRFact_Date = R_Fact_Date,
        @LRFact_No = R_Fact_No,
        @LRStock_Cd = R_Stock_Cd
    FROM 
        S_Fifo_Gheymat
    WHERE 
        Acc_Year = @AYear 
        AND Od_Cd = @OdCd 
        AND (@SCd = 0 OR H_Stock_Cd = @SCd)
        AND EXISTS (SELECT Id 
                    FROM S_Dtl_Fct 
                    WHERE Id = H_Id 
                      AND Radif = H_Radif 
                      AND Stock_Cd = H_Stock_Cd 
                      AND Od_Cd = S_Fifo_Gheymat.Od_Cd) 
       AND EXISTS (SELECT Id 
                   FROM S_Dtl_Fct 
                   WHERE Id = R_Id 
                     AND Radif = R_Radif 
                     AND Stock_Cd = R_Stock_Cd 
                     AND Od_Cd = S_Fifo_Gheymat.Od_Cd) 

SELECT @LHId=ISNULL(@LHId,0),@LHRadif=IsNull(@LHRadif,0),@LHFact_Date=IsNull
(@LHFact_Date,@StartDate),@LHFact_No=IsNull(@LHFact_No,0),@LHStock_Cd=ISNULL
(@LHStock_Cd,0)
    ,@LQnt_Resid=ISNULL(@LQnt_Resid,0),@LPrc_Resid=ISNULL(@LPrc_Resid,0)
    ,@LRId=ISNULL(@LRId,0),@LRRadif=IsNull(@LRRadif,0),@LRFact_Date=IsNull
(@LRFact_Date,@StartDate),@LRFact_No=IsNull(@LRFact_No,0),@LRStock_Cd=ISNULL
(@LRStock_Cd,0)
---------------------------------------
IF @LDate IS NULL BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @LDate=Fact_Date
    FROM S_Dtl_Fct D
    LEFT OUTER JOIN S_Hed_Fct H ON D.Id=H.Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.S_STOCKS S ON D.Stock_Cd=S.Stock_Cd
    LEFT OUTER JOIN U_Log U ON H.Id_Log=U.Id_Log AND U.Action_Cd=5 
    WHERE (H.Acc_Year=@AYear) AND (H.Flag=6) AND (D.Od_Cd=@OdCd) AND 
(H.Tamam=0) AND (@SCd<>0 OR S.Estesna_Gp=0)
        AND (
                (H.Fact_Date>@LHFact_Date)
                OR (H.Fact_Date=@LHFact_Date AND 
H.Fact_No>@LHFact_No)
                OR (H.Fact_Date=@LHFact_Date AND 
H.Fact_No=@LHFact_No AND D.Radif>@LHRadif)
                OR (H.Fact_Date=@LHFact_Date AND 
H.Fact_No=@LHFact_No AND D.Radif=@LHRadif AND D.Stock_Cd>@LHStock_Cd)
            )
        AND (@SCd=0 OR D.Stock_Cd=@SCd) AND (H.VAZEIAT<>2) AND 
(U.Id_Log IS NOT NULL)
    ORDER BY H.Fact_Date
End
DECLARE @H TABLE (   H_Id INT,H_Radif SMALLINT,H_Fact_Date CHAR
(8),H_Fact_No INT,H_Stock_Cd TINYINT,Quantity Decimal(18,4),Un_Prc 
MONEY,HTamam Bit
                    ,R_Id INT,R_Radif SMALLINT,R_Fact_Date 
CHAR(8),R_Fact_No INT,R_Stock_Cd TINYINT,Qnt_Resid Decimal(18,2),Prc_Resid 
Decimal(30,8))
INSERT INTO @H 
(H_Id,H_Radif,H_Fact_Date,H_Fact_No,H_Stock_Cd,Quantity,HTamam)
SELECT D.Id,D.Radif,H.Fact_Date,H.Fact_No,D.Stock_Cd,D.Quantity,H.Tamam
FROM S_Dtl_Fct D
LEFT OUTER JOIN S_Hed_Fct H ON D.Id=H.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.S_STOCKS S ON D.Stock_Cd=S.Stock_Cd
WHERE (H.Acc_Year=@AYear) AND (H.Flag=6) AND (D.Od_Cd=@OdCd) AND 
(H.Fact_Date<=@LDate) AND (@SCd<>0 OR S.Estesna_Gp=0)
    AND (
            (H.Fact_Date>@LHFact_Date)
            OR (H.Fact_Date=@LHFact_Date AND H.Fact_No>@LHFact_No)
            OR (H.Fact_Date=@LHFact_Date AND H.Fact_No=@LHFact_No 
AND D.Radif>@LHRadif)
            OR (H.Fact_Date=@LHFact_Date AND H.Fact_No=@LHFact_No 
AND D.Radif=@LHRadif AND D.Stock_Cd>@LHStock_Cd)
        )
    AND (@SCd=0 OR D.Stock_Cd=@SCd) AND (H.VAZEIAT<>2)
ORDER BY H.Fact_Date,H.Fact_No,D.Radif,D.Stock_Cd
Delete S_Related_RH FROM @H H LEFT OUTER JOIN S_Related_RH R ON 
H.H_Id=R.H_Id AND H.H_Radif=R.H_Radif 
------------------------------------------
DECLARE @HQnt DECIMAL(18,4),@HDate CHAR(8),@SumQ DECIMAL(18,4),@SumG 
MONEY,@HQntWithPrc DECIMAL(18,4)
SET @SumG=@LQnt_Resid*@LPrc_Resid
SET @SumQ=@LQnt_Resid
--
DECLARE Cr CURSOR FOR SELECT Quantity,H_Fact_Date,H_Id,H_Radif FROM @H FOR 
UPDATE OF Un_Prc
Open Cr
Fetch Next From Cr InTo @HQnt,@HDate,@LHId,@LHRadif
While (@@Fetch_Status=0) AND (@LRId IS NOT NULL)
Begin
    IF @HQnt<=@LQnt_Resid BEGIN
        SET @LQnt_Resid=@LQnt_Resid-@HQnt
        UPDATE @H SET    
Un_Prc=@SumG/@SumQ,R_Id=@LRId,R_Radif=@LRRadif,R_Fact_Date=@LRFact_Date,
R_Fact_No=@LRFact_No,R_Stock_Cd=@LRStock_Cd
                        ,Qnt_Resid=@LQnt_Resid,Prc_Resid=@LPrc_Resid
        WHERE CURRENT OF Cr
        IF @HQnt>0 BEGIN
            INSERT INTO dbo.S_Related_RH  
(H_Id,H_Radif,R_Id,R_Radif,Quantity)
            VALUES (@LHId,@LHRadif,@LRId,@LRRadif,@HQnt)
        END

        SET @SumG=@LQnt_Resid*@LPrc_Resid
        SET @SumQ=@LQnt_Resid

        Fetch Next From Cr InTo @HQnt,@HDate,@LHId,@LHRadif

    END ELSE BEGIN


        IF @LQnt_Resid>0 BEGIN
            INSERT INTO dbo.S_Related_RH 
 (H_Id,H_Radif,R_Id,R_Radif,Quantity)
            VALUES (@LHId,@LHRadif,@LRId,@LRRadif,@LQnt_Resid)
        END

        SET @HQnt=@HQnt-@LQnt_Resid --مقدار باقیمانده حواله

SELECT TOP 1 
@LRId=D.Id,@LRRadif=D.Radif,@LRFact_Date=H.Fact_Date,@LRFact_No=H.Fact_No,
@LRStock_Cd=D.Stock_Cd,@LQnt_Resid=D.QUANTITY
                    ,@LPrc_Resid=CASE D.QUANTITY WHEN 0  
THEN 0 ELSE ( (Un_Prc*D.QUANTITY)+ISNULL(Qnt_1,0) )/ D.QUANTITY END 
        FROM S_Dtl_Fct D
        LEFT OUTER JOIN S_Hed_Fct H ON D.Id=H.Id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.S_STOCKS S ON D.Stock_Cd=S.Stock_Cd
        WHERE (H.Acc_Year=@AYear) AND (H.Flag=5) AND (D.Od_Cd=@OdCd) 
AND (H.Fact_Date<=@HDate) AND (H.Tamam=1) AND (@SCd<>0 OR S.Estesna_Gp=0)
            AND (
                    (H.Fact_Date>@LRFact_Date)
                    OR (H.Fact_Date=@LRFact_Date AND 
H.Fact_No>@LRFact_No)
                    OR (H.Fact_Date=@LRFact_Date AND 
H.Fact_No=@LRFact_No AND D.Radif>@LRRadif)
                    OR (H.Fact_Date=@LRFact_Date AND 
H.Fact_No=@LRFact_No AND D.Radif=@LRRadif AND D.Stock_Cd>@LRStock_Cd)
                )
            AND (@SCd=0 OR D.Stock_Cd=@SCd) AND (H.VAZEIAT<>2)
        ORDER BY H.Fact_Date,H.Fact_No,D.Radif,D.Stock_Cd

        --
        IF @LRId IS NOT NULL BEGIN
            IF @HQnt<=@LQnt_Resid SET @HQntWithPrc=@HQnt ELSE SET 
@HQntWithPrc=@LQnt_Resid
            SET @SumG=@SumG+(@HQntWithPrc*@LPrc_Resid) 
            SET @SumQ=@SumQ+@HQntWithPrc 

        End
        IF ISNULL(@LQnt_Resid,0)=0 Break
    End
END
Close Cr
Deallocate Cr
DECLARE @E Int
SET @E=0    
BEGIN TRAN
    UPDATE D SET Un_Prc=G.Un_Prc
    FROM S_Dtl_Fct D
    INNER JOIN @H G ON D.Id=G.H_Id AND D.Radif=G.H_Radif
    WHERE (G.HTamam=0) And (G.R_Id IS NOT NULL)

    SET @Cnt=@@ROWCOUNT
    Set @E=@E+@@Error

    DELETE F FROM S_Fifo_Gheymat F
    WHERE (Acc_Year=@Ayear) AND (@SCd=0 OR H_Stock_Cd=@SCd) AND 
(Od_Cd=@OdCd)
        And EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 Od_Cd
                    FROM @H
                    WHERE (H_Stock_Cd=F.H_Stock_Cd) AND 
(Od_Cd=@OdCd) AND (R_Id IS NOT NULL)
                    ORDER BY H_Fact_Date DESC ,H_Fact_No 
 DESC ,H_Radif DESC ,H_Stock_Cd DESC)

    Set @E=@E+@@Error

    INSERT INTO S_Fifo_Gheymat 
 (Acc_Year,H_Stock_Cd,OD_CD,R_Stock_Cd,H_Id,H_Fact_Date,H_Fact_No,
 H_Radif,R_Id,R_Fact_Date,R_Fact_No,R_Radif,Qnt_Resid,Prc_Resid)
    SELECT TOP 1    
  @AYear,H_Stock_Cd,@OdCd,R_Stock_Cd,H_Id,H_Fact_Date,H_Fact_No,H_Radif,
  R_Id,R_Fact_Date,R_Fact_No,R_Radif,Qnt_Resid,Prc_Resid
    FROM @H
    WHERE R_Id IS NOT Null
    ORDER BY H_Fact_Date DESC ,H_Fact_No DESC ,H_Radif DESC ,H_Stock_Cd Desc

    Set @E=@E+@@Error
IF @E=0 COMMIT TRAN ELSE ROLLBACK TRAN

SELECT @Cnt Cnt,@LHFact_No LHFactNo,@LHFact_Date LHFactDate,@LHStock_Cd 
LHStock_Cd,@LRFact_No LRFactNo,@LRFact_Date LRFactDate,@LRStock_Cd 
LRStock_Cd
```

Comment: Not enough info here to answer...  But what's left to differ are the server configs (sys tables). Brute force would be two text dumps of sys. And then check for diff's. All of your column  and var names suggest numerics, so charset/collation diff's aren't the problem. In what way do the two results differ?

Comment: Your example does not help us. It is hard to read, way too complicated, we know nothing about your environments and server settings. And yes, of course it is possible to have different results when you have different configurations. Some settings are directly affecting the way SQL Server behaves.

Answer (score 1):

Without a copy of your db (not a request) it's not possible to answer this.

> Is it possible that the configuration of SQL Server affects how a
>   query returns results?

Yes this is a possibility. For example, if your [ANSI NULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql) settings are different between the two servers then NULL will be equal to NULL on the server has ANSI_NULL set to on OFF but not on the server where ANSI_NULL is ON. [Collation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations) is another. If one server has a case sensitive collation the "A" and "a" are not equal whereas the opposite is true using the SQL Server default. These are just a couple examples.

That said, they way to isolate the problem is to break the stored proc up into parts and try to identify where the differences are starting. In the first steps, where you assign variables, add a step to dump them into a temp table that you can summarize and compare across both servers. If there's no differences keep moving down the proc running each part until you find a difference. Often I'll comment everything out then uncomment code from top-to-bottom until I isolate the problem.

Lastly, you are using couple cursors here and don't need to. You can simplify your code by making it more set-based and therefore less verbose. It will be much easier to troubleshoot and will perform much, much better.