# Mysql same version (5.6.27) behaving differently on 2 different servers

Tags: mysql

I have mysql 5.6.27 installed on my two servers.

Database has a table which has a column type `bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL`.

While inserting a string type value (like 1_2_3_4) in this column on one server it storing value 1 and showing a data truncation warning.

But if i am executing the same query on another server it showing the error message for data truncation and not letting the value inserted.

Just trying to understand why mysql is casting the value on one server but not on another.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Same query, same database, different server, different result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47129426/same-query-same-database-different-server-different-result)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a configuration issue, specifically strict settings, see https://www.davidpashley.com/2009/02/15/silently-truncated/